# Do we have support for TLS 1.3 in .NET Framework v4.8?

Tags: tcp, ftp-client, .net-4.8, tls1.3, windows-11

We have an FTP Client written in .NET Framework v4.8 using TCP. We notice that the our FTP client application does not connect an FTP Server that has TLS 1.3 support. We are running the FTP Client in Windows 11 OS, which officially supports TLS 1.3. We also enabled the TLS 1.3 support via registry hack and followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#for-tcp-sockets-networking) recommendation. But still, our FTP Client is unable to connect to the FTP server via TLS 1.3.

Also, According to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/4675#issuecomment-768880551) article, it states that TLS 1.3 support would come in mid-2021 in .NET Framework, however, there is no latest information.

Does anyone know if .NET Framework v4.8 supports TLS 1.3 or not? I could not find any good article which clarify this statement.

Comment: I have similar problem, do you have any update?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to connect to a .NET server using TLSv1.3, hosting a service using `System.ServicesModel.ServiceHost`. I couldn't get it to work in Windows 10 though.